# Chrome Extensions: Getting Content Scripts To Work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am learning how to build simple extensions that use content scripts. To do so, I am tweaking existing sample extensions to get a lay of the land -- or at least that is the goal.

Problem is, none of the sample extensions that use content scripts seem to work for me. Two simple ones that should work but are not are:  Email this Page, and SandwichBar (Direct link to zipped extension folder http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/infobars/sandwichbar.zip ).

I am using Chrome 16.0.912.75  on a Linux box. Any ideas why this might be the case? Conflicting extensions or overriding flags? I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Thank You!

Comment: You really should update your browser, currently 23 is the stable version, and 25 is already in making.

Comment: What Linux distro are you using? I believe that you'd better ask "How to get the latest version of Chrome?" at http://superuser.com/, http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I updated it to the current version. I assumed I had it setup to upgrade automatically, but turned out to not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Sandwitch bar do not work because it uses info bar experimental API [manifest version 2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're using a really old version of Chrome (in internet years at least). They change the APIs from time to time, and probably something they've done in the interim has broken content scripts in Chrome 16 (for example the change from `sendRequest` to `sendMessage`). Isn't a more recent version of Chrome available for your platform?